# How to override theme definition

Tags: asp.net

Take the following theme example:

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"></asp:GridView>
```

If i set these values to False in a grid, .Net will still use those defined on the theme.

How can I override these settings?

Comment: what you mean saying theme definition. Are you referring to the style? The Paging and Sorting are some behaviors that can be defined for a gridview they haven't any relationship with the theme of gridview.

Comment: it's a simplified example. You can set a value on the theme to use in most grids, but you don't want to use it in one